# Use of undeclared type 'XXX', Xcode 7.3, swift 2.2

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode7.3, swift2

Code like this was fine in swift 2.1:

```
var completionHandler: AWSContinuationBlock
```

But now have error in swift 2.2:

> Use of undeclared type 'AWSContinuationBlock'

The definition of `AWSContinuationBlock` is as the following in Objective-C:

```
@interface AWSTask<__covariant ResultType> : NSObject

/*!
 A block that can act as a continuation for a task.
 */
typedef __nullable id(^AWSContinuationBlock)(AWSTask<ResultType> *task);

... 
@end
```

According to the discussion about `enum` in this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/33419), it seems that if we move the defintion out side of the `@interface` `@end` then it will work. But cannot simply do that here because of the template variant `ResultType`. So, how do we solve the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Above the line,

```
var completionHandler: AWSContinuationBlock
```

Try rewriting the code...var completionHandler: AWSCo to see if the "term" has changed in Xcode 7